# How to configure owa to add the HTTP header X-FRAME-OPTIONS to the respond?

Tags: security, http-headers, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

my OWA server has suffered from click jacking and I know I have to add HTTP header

```
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
```

to the respond, but I don't know exactly how I can do it.

Please if any one can provide me a way to solve this issue, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps helped me to solve this problem, Here are the steps:

1- Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.

2- In Features View, double-click HTTP Response Headers.

3- On the HTTP Response Headers page, in the Actions pane, click Add.

4- In the Add Custom HTTP Response Header dialog box, add a header called "X-FRAME-OPTIONS", and assign it's value to "SAMEORIGIN".

5- Click OK.

For more information, Please visit the following link:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn´t change the IIS configuration by hand. The correct way is to use the Microsoft way to configure that. So at first check the current state from that option via:

```
get-OWAVirtualDirectory -Identity "exchange1\owa (Default Web Site)" | select WebPartsFrameOptionsType
```

It that stands on "None" then you can change that to SameOrigin via the following way:

```
Set-OWAVirtualDirectory -Identity "exchange1\owa (Default Web Site)" -WebPartsFrameOptionsType SameOrigin
```

Please keep noted that AllowFrom isn´t yet supported as written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123515(v=exchg.160).aspx).

Optional:

You can control that via the OWA mailbox Policy:

To check the status use:

```
get-OwaMailboxPolicy -Identity "OWA User Policy" | select WebPartsFrameOptionsType
```

To change that use:

```
Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -Identity "OWA User Policy" -WebPartsFrameOptionsType SameOrigin
```

*More infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123515(v=exchg.160).aspx) or [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/01/20/owa-web-parts-not-working-in-2013-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame/)*